Differential Consequences and the Dimension of the Submanifold Representing a DE system
Let $\Delta^{(s_0)} = 0$ be a set of differential equations (DEs). Suppose that I prolong it to $\Delta^{(s_0+1)}$ using the total derivative operator $D_j$, where $j=1,\dotsc,p$ and $p$ is the number of independent variables. Now, assume that it generated an algebraically redundant constraint, say $\Delta^{(s_0+1), l_{s_0+1}}=0$, where $l_{s_0+1} \in \{1, \dotsc, n_{s_0+1}\}$ and $n_{s_0+1}$ is the number of newly introduced constraints at $(s_0+1)^{th} $ prolongation step. Let $\Sigma^{(s_0+1)}\subset J^{(s_0+1)}(M)$ be the submanifold specified by all these constraints, i.e. $\{\Delta^{(s_0)} = 0, \Delta^{(s_0+1)} = 0\}$.
My question is: Under the assumption that $\Sigma^{(s_0)}$ and $\Sigma^{(s_0+1)}$ are regular, whether the rank of the Jacobian matrix $\text{Jac}(\Delta^{(s_0)}, \Delta^{(s_0+1)})$, is affected by the redundant constraints, such as $\Delta^{(s_0+1), l_{s_0+1}}=0$ stated above?
I think, algebraically, they are already included in the ideal generated by the associated Grobner basis. On the other hand, since a differential ideal should also be closed under partial differentiation operator, I could not be sure of my own conclusion.
